# Use a string as part of an If statement (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an If/Then loop in VBA that checks if the same cell in each tab are equal, and I can create a string that works in the If/Then loop given a known number of tabs (3 tabs); however, the macro needs to look at an arbitrary number of tabs and I need a dynamic If/Then statement. I tried to create a string that essentially writes the code based on the number of tabs, but I get Type Mismatch because the string is a variable.

For example, this works given 3 tabs:

```
If Worksheets(loc(1)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) = Worksheets(loc(2)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) _
   And Worksheets(loc(1)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) = Worksheets(loc(3)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) Then
```

....

But this doesn't work:

```
ifline = "Worksheets(loc(1)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) = Worksheets(loc(2)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) _
   And Worksheets(loc(1)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) = Worksheets(loc(3)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15)"

If ifline Then ....
```

I also tried using Evalulate(ifline) and StrConv(ifline) to no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this is a terrible approach but here you go http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/          post your code and we can help you get there

Comment: Use a `For Each` loop to loop through the sheets. And compare each sheet to the first.  If any are false then do not do the rest. Then assign a Boolean variable true or false based on the outcome.  Then you can test on that Boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

You can easily test against other sheet names if there are sheets you know you don't want to check against.

```
Dim sValue As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("loc(1)")

sValue = ws1.Cells(TseriesLine, 15).Value2

Dim bifline As Boolean
bifline = True

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
        If sValue <> ws.Cells(TseriesLine, 15).Value2 Then
            bifline = False
            Exit For
        End
    End If

Next

If bifline Then
    'more code
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each sheet with the worksheet collection in each workbook object.

```
Function doesRangeMatch(rangeAddress As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(rangeAddress).Value <> ws.Range(rangeAddress).Value Then
            doesRangeMatch = False 
            Exit Function 'early exit if match not found
        End If
    Next
    doesRangeMatch = True 'if loop goes through then all must match
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone so much! I used a combination of suggestions to come up with the loop. Here is the solution:

```
For ss = 2 To numloc
    If Worksheets(loc(1)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) <> Worksheets(loc(ss)).Cells(TseriesLine, 15) Then
        doNumMatch = False
Exit For
    Else: doNumMatch = True
    End If
Next

If doNumMatch Then
```